# replace one external image with another internal in php

Tags: javascript, image, replace, external

Is there a function to replace one image with another
Example
I want to replace the external image in the output

```
<img src="http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/images/mozodojo-original-image.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail ">
```

with a internal image

```
<img src="http://www.alforat.org/attachments/4309d1250860423-12image-insolite02.jpg" alt="" class="thumbnail ">
```

Comment: Replace where? in the FTP? in the output?

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from? Are you generating it yourself or fetching it from an external source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is Javascript, not PHP.
Php is server-side language, while Javascript is client-side.

To make your life with Javascript easier, You should use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), try setting an id for your img and then :

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","http://www.alforat.org/attachments/4309d1250860423-12image-insolite02.jpg");
```

About how to handle that, where to put it and how to write Javascript, try [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)